# How to access fb access token form server running program ( python )

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have developed a fb app and the front end side is working great with my own db.

Now I want to make a python program that runs through the command line which posts to my fb account. 
I know with this I need to access the access token as I come across this while access my app outside fb which does not function properly unless run inside the fb iframe. 
So is there a python sdk etc so that I can access the access token and or storing the access token in the db so python can pull it out then use the python sdk to post if exists.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> PyFacebook is a thin wrapper for accessing Facebook's RESTful API through Python.

https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk

> facebook-sdk, a set of essential tools for working with Facebook in Python.
>   django-facebook, an extensible django plugin for building facebook integrated sites.

http://www.pythonforfacebook.com/

Comment: Thanks Paul, i guess it is ok to store the access token in the db so python can pull it out?