# Query about expiry of access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access fb access token form server running program ( python )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758961/how-to-access-fb-access-token-form-server-running-program-python)

Right i know that the access token expires after 2 hours or 60 days depending on if it's server or client side. The thing i can not work out is that some apps does not ask to reauthorize the access token after 2h or 60d through the app control panel. So how is it possible due the offline access being removed. It's proper confusing. Is it possible to get a new access token without the users access as this is the only thing i can think of that might be the solution.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [How to access fb access token form server running program ( python )](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12758961/how-to-access-fb-access-token-form-server-running-program-python) and http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13010705/just-a-query-about-the-access-token – please stick to __one__ question for one topic, instead of opening a new one every few days.

Comment: That one was about accessing the access token using python. So I can't see how this is to do with this one as it's about php plus about reauthorising not accessing the token.

Answer (score 0):

> The thing i can not work out is that some apps does not ask to reauthorize the access token after 2h or 60d *through the app control panel.*

(I suppose you mean the Auth dialog here?)

Some actions can be undertaken with the app access token, as long as the user has given the necessary permission once – no matter if the original user access token is already expired.

> Is it possible to get a new access token without the users access

It is not possible to get a new user access token without any user interaction.

But having a user who has already given an app permission once visit a page with the JS SDK embedded will give a new user access token without requiring any further active contribution by the user.

Comment: Arh ok. The only problem is that my php commandline program needs to update the db with the new access token and this is outside the browser. So i guess i'll need to pass the oauth url through my commandline program to get a new access token then just update the db with it?. Edit: As when i update the the field via my web app and the access token expiry error goes away so i just need the command program to do this instead of the user.

Comment: Sorry if it seemed i duplicated the post which it might have been. I have another quick question. While reading a post on here it says that as long as the app as permission to the users account it could post for 100years without expiring. Then also it says that the token expires after up to 2hours or 60days depending. To me this seems confusing as which one is true. Sorry it's probably me not reading things properly i can not understand this.